# 20.04: Boot hangs after kernel upgrade

Tags: boot, 20.04, kernel

A while ago I upgraded the kernel on a 20.04.2 test-server VM (on Hyper-V 2019) to 5.4.0-72-generic. Yesterday I noticed that the previous boot hang right at the start with the message "EFI stub: UEFI Secure Boot is enabled." But another Ubuntu server VM on the same host boots fine, secure boot and all.

When I disable Secure Boot, the boot process still hangs early on, showing "Loading initial RAM disk" right after the boot manager. Same with 5.4.0-71-generic but the old 5.4.0-66-generic still boots. So I booted with the oldest kernel and did `update-grub`. Now the newest kernel does not even show the "Loading Linux 5.4.0-72-generic/Loading initial RAM disk" message anymore, otherwise there are no changes. I also noticed that `shutdown -r` no longer seems to work, I get the Hyper-V UEFI splash screen and that's that :-( The server seems to run docker/containerd and tgtd, nothing else apart from the usual Ubuntu stuff.

Any ideas / pointers where to go from here?

**Update**: It's probably not a problem with the kernel, so I asked a more general question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1337612/how-to-debug-boot-problems).

Comment: Tried the `boot-repair` rescue disk and now it displays some text, then a nice graphical "Ubuntu 20.04" progress bar but still hangs after "cloud-init .... finished at ...". AND boot-repair removed the boot manager screen. Now I can't even boot into the old 5.4.0-66 kernel :-(